# what to use instead of ` Command Argument property`in a` gridview` When I create the gridview in client side using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Suppose I have following table in my database:

```
Tbl_Persons: 
 Id   Country    Name    
 1    Australia  Ben   
 2    Japan      John
 3    Korea      Libby
 4    Australia  Raymond
```

I use following Query and bind the result using `DataTable` to a `Gridview`.

```
select id,Country,Name 
       from tbl_persons
           where country='Australia'
```

In `gridview` I have two `Bound Columns` and 1 `template column`.
In template column I typically put an `ImageButton` and assign the `ID field` to `image button` using `Command Argumnet property`. And when user clicks on the `imagebutton` in the browser  I'll get the `command argument value` in sever an do some operations with it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ountry" HeaderText="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

As you know in runtime mode when user views the source of code in browser the values of `command argument` are not observable because they create in server. and user can't change the values using  the browser and send the changed values to the server.

But `gridview` is server side an has post back. So I use `jquery` and fill `My gridview` with appending `tr` and `td` tags in client side.
For `ID field of my database` because I don't have `command argument` in client side I assign the `Id` of each `TD` tag equals to the `Id field`.
But the user can change the `Id values` in the browser and send invalid data to the server and this is a disaster.
This is piece of my code:

```
script type="text/javascript">
  function BindGridView() {
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/GetNames",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
         for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#NamesGridView").append("<tr><td id="+data.d[i].Id+">" + data.d[i].Country + 
                                            "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr>");
             }
           }
          })
      }
</script>
```

So what can I do to prevent user to changes the values?
Are there any ways something like Command Argument in client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Web.UI.Page

_
 _
 _
 _
Public Class AutoCompleteService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function GetPhysicianCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
    Dim lstItem As New List(Of String)
    Dim pag As New Page
    Dim oCommon As Common = CType(Context.Session("CommonSetting"), Common)
    Dim oDataSet As New System.Data.DataSet
    Dim SQLConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = Nothing
    Try
        SQLConn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(General.ConnectionString)
        SQLConn.Open()
        Dim param As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(SQLConn, "TempAutocompletePhysician")
        ' @AccountID AS INT 

        param(0).Value = oCommon.AccountID  'CInt(contextKey)

        ' @prefixText AS VARCHAR(50) 
        param(1).Value = prefixText

        oDataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SQLConn, Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "TempAutocompletePhysician", param)

        For Each oRow As System.Data.DataRow In oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
            lstItem.Add(oRow("Context").ToString)
            If lstItem.Count = count Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return lstItem.ToArray()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return lstItem.ToArray()
    Finally
        If SQLConn IsNot Nothing AndAlso SQLConn.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLConn.Close()
            SQLConn = Nothing
        End If
        oDataSet = Nothing
    End Try

   a
    'Return lstItem.ToArray()
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: check this code here i am use session to return particular data

Comment: when data comes from user you don't have any way .. always send to server

Comment: What is your idea about  simulating something like digital signature?

Comment: I encrypt the id value with a private key and in client side I have something like `<td id=1;encrypted value>` and when user clicks on the image button in `web method` I encrypt the the value that is not encrypted heres is 1 value. and I compare the encrypted result with previous encrypted one. If they are the same so data is not changed else it is changed so data is invalid

Comment: Checking with database is costly too isn't it?

Comment: This is a sample code I have written before in my page-load for the other purpose:`string cities;
            string PlainCity;
            PlainCity = Request.Form[HideCity2.UniqueID];
            SymmetricEncryption SmE = new SymmetricEncryption();
            if (SmE.Encrypt(PlainCity,"Password!") != Request.Form[HideCity.UniqueID])
            {
                //LblTotalError.Visible = true;
                return;
            }`

Comment: `smo2201@yahoo`.com. I am online now with Yahoo messenger . you can chat me.

Answer (score 1):

At this time your have to use web service, jquery call web service and send and receive data with use of JSON..

Comment: if wrong id send that simply show message that id is wrong.... or send some thing which indicate that id is wrong...

Comment: according to my select statement the grid view shows `1 Ben, 4 Raymond`.and when user clicks on the image button I can show some details information according to the Id. but If  someone changes the Id and send it to server the end user can see the details information of the other record. for example if changes id=1 to id=2 can see John details  information and it is a disaster. so the value is not wrong, it is forbidden to see.

Comment: yah its something complex but you can send some credential for valid data to access particular user

Comment: are your calling web service for web or for perticular application onlt /

Comment: create web service which is use within a web site .. not host it.. juts use it as locally

Comment: and one more thing use Session in web service if you called in  within a project

Comment: use   <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _ in webservice so you can use session

Comment: Could you explain me more about credentials?

Comment: I don't have any problem about web services, pleases say me what credentials can I use to check is the inserted Id is a forbidden one or not.

Comment: is you grid view display all data ? or display  only data for particular user ?

Comment: ya if you use session with web service you can do it.. you can check it in function where data is for valid user or not

Comment: Should I always check in server, Aren't there any other ways?

Comment: I'm thinking about digital signature. what is your idea about it?